# Returning altered text after Markdown to HTML Conversion

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm creating my own markdown-to-html converter. In this piece of code the text should be returned bolded, but it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
def query(request, title_name):
    content = util.get_entry(title_name)
    bold_pattern = re.compile('[(\*\*|__)]{2}(?P<bold_text>[\w\s]+)[(\*\*|__)]{2}')
    bold_matches = re.finditer(bold_pattern, content)
    new = ""
    for match in bold_matches:
        pos_x = content.find(match.group())
        pos_y = pos_x+len(match.group())
        new = re.sub(bold_pattern, match.group("bold_text"), content[pos_x:pos_y])
        content = content.replace(content[pos_x:pos_y], f'<b>{new}</b>')
        mark_safe(content)
      
    return render(request, ".../entry.html",{
        "content": content,
        "title": util.get_page_name(title_name)
    })
```

Is there something im missing before returning it to HTML?
Here is my simple entry.html:

```
{% extends ".../layout.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
{{content}}

<p>Edit this page <a href="{% url 'edit' title %}">here</a></p> 

{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Auto-Escaping

By default, the django template engine escapes all HTML-characters which are passed into the template. You can read about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#how-to-turn-it-off).

To switch off the autoescape for just one variable, use:
`{{content|safe}}`